# In- place quick sort - Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a in-place quick sort. I understand it using sub-arrays, but in-place is really throwing me.

Having an example in Ruby would really help, but I haven been able to find one. Could some one provide me with an example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is not very clear what your problem is. Could you show the code with sub-arrays that you understand? I would assume you don't want to see an answer with `array.sort!` in it, but other than that I am really not sure what you are asking. Is it related to this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Ruby ?

Comment: Doing a quick Google search for "ruby in-place quick sort" generates several examples.  Check those out and let us know if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to understand it in code, there's a number of very elegant explanations of the quicksort algorithm out there.  Here are a few of my favorite illustrations which may help your understanding.

- [With cups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZaf_9IZCrc)
- [With Hungarian Dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8)

As for a Ruby example, [the answers to this question cover that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371681/quick-sort-in-ruby-language).