# In ruby, Is it better to receive *array or to duplicate and array inside a method?

Tags: ruby, quicksort

I was playing around with some implementations of [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) in Ruby. After implementing some of the inlace algorithms,  I felt that using Ruby's [partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html) method,  even though it would not provide an in-place solution, it would provide a very nice readable solution.

My first solution was this, which other than always using the last element of the array as the pivot, seemed pretty nice.

```
def quick_sort3(ary)
  return ary if ary.size <= 1
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < ary.last }
  pivot_value = right.pop
  quick_sort3(left) + [pivot_value] +  quick_sort3(right)
end
```

After some searching I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387864/2612259) which had a very similar solution with a better choice of the initial pivot, reproduced here using the same variable names and block passed to partition.

```
def quick_sort6(*ary)
  return ary if ary.empty?
  pivot_value = ary.delete_at(rand(ary.size))
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < pivot_value }
  return *quick_sort6(*left), pivot_value, *quick_sort6(*right)
end
```

I felt I could improve my solution by using the same method to select a random pivot.

```
def quick_sort4(ary)
  return ary if ary.size <= 1
  pivot_value = ary.delete_at(rand(ary.size))
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < pivot_value }
  quick_sort4(left) + [pivot_value] +  quick_sort4(right)
end
```

The down side to this version quick_sort4 vs the linked answer quick_sort6, is that quick_sort4 changes the input array, while quick_sort6 does not.  I am assuming this is why Jorg chose to receive the splat array vs array?

My fix for this was to simply duplicate the passed in array and then perform the delete_at on the copied array rather than the original array.

```
def quick_sort5(ary_in)
  return ary_in if ary_in.size <= 1
  ary = ary_in.dup
  pivot_value = ary.delete_at(rand(ary.size))
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < pivot_value }
  quick_sort5(left) + [pivot_value] +  quick_sort5(right)
end
```

My question is there any significant differences between quick_sort6 which uses the splats and quick_sort5 which uses dup?  I am assuming the use of the splats was to avoid changing the input array,  but is there something else I am missing?

Comment: If you can avoid `dup` and write functional code that doesn't modify the inputs then you usually end up with better code. Your #3 solution seems good in that regard. The others are more of a hack, what with leaning on the splat and using `delete_at`, which involves a lot of array shuffling. `pop` is cheap by comparison,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, `quick_sort6` is your best bet. Using some random data:

```
require 'benchmark'

def quick_sort3(ary)
  return ary if ary.size <= 1
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < ary.last }
  pivot_value = right.pop
  quick_sort3(left) + [pivot_value] +  quick_sort3(right)
end

def quick_sort6(*ary)
  return ary if ary.empty?
  pivot_value = ary.delete_at(rand(ary.size))
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < pivot_value }
  return *quick_sort6(*left), pivot_value, *quick_sort6(*right)
end

def quick_sort4(ary)
  return ary if ary.size <= 1
  pivot_value = ary.delete_at(rand(ary.size))
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < pivot_value }
  quick_sort4(left) + [pivot_value] +  quick_sort4(right)
end

def quick_sort5(ary_in)
  return ary_in if ary_in.size <= 1
  ary = ary_in.dup
  pivot_value = ary.delete_at(rand(ary.size))
  left,right = ary.partition { |v| v < pivot_value }
  quick_sort5(left) + [pivot_value] +  quick_sort5(right)
end

random_arrays = Array.new(5000) do
  Array.new(500) { rand(1...500) }.uniq
end

Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
  benchmark.report("quick_sort3") do
    random_arrays.each do |ra|
      quick_sort3(ra.dup)
    end
  end
  benchmark.report("quick_sort6") do
    random_arrays.each do |ra|
      quick_sort6(ra.dup)
    end
  end
  benchmark.report("quick_sort4") do
    random_arrays.each do |ra|
      quick_sort4(ra.dup)
    end
  end
  benchmark.report("quick_sort5") do
    random_arrays.each do |ra|
      quick_sort5(ra.dup)
    end
  end
end
```

Gives as result

```
       user     system      total        real
quick_sort3  1.389173   0.019380   1.408553 (  1.411771)
quick_sort6  0.004399   0.000022   0.004421 (  0.004487)
quick_sort4  1.208003   0.002573   1.210576 (  1.214131)
quick_sort5  1.458327   0.000867   1.459194 (  1.459882)
```

Comment: Very interesting.  I would still love to know why that method is so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with splat style in this case is that it would create an awkward API.

Most times the consumer code would have an array of things that need to be sorted:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
sort(stuff)
```

The splat style makes the consumers do this instead:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
sort(*stuff)
```

The two calls might end up doing the same thing, but *as a user* I am sorting an array, therefore I expect to pass the array to the method, not pass each array element individually to the method.

Another label for this phenomenon in [abstraction leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) - you are allowing the implementation of the sort method define its interface. Usually in Ruby this is frowned upon.